# Angular 7 - How to init a array object with json dataset?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient

Im trying to init my MatTableDatasource from an json Object retried from spotify API,
I created a model in order to manipulate my data easly but when I init my Array with JSON object, I can't access to the attribute of my object in my new array.

Here is what I tried,
https://i.imgur.com/dzpxB0Q

```
updateCurrentTrackList(idPlaylist: string): void {
        const tracksListUrl = this.spotifyUrl + '/playlists/' + idPlaylist + '/tracks?limit=100&fields=items.track(name,href,album(name,href))';
        this._http.get<any>(tracksListUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
                let listeTrack: Track[] = [];
                for ( let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++ ) {
                    listeTrack.push(
                        {
                            name: data.items[i].name,
                            href: data.items[i].href,
                            album: {name: data.items[i].album.name, href: data.items[i].href }
                        }
                    );
                }
                return listeTrack;
            })
        ).subscribe(
            (result: Track []) => {
               /* result.forEach((value) => {
                    this.currentTracksList.push(value);
                });*/
                this.currentTracksList = result

                this.currrentTracksListSubject.next(this.currentTracksList);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.currrentTracksListSubject.next(this.currentTracksList);
            }
        );
```

result from console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

```
{"items":[{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/37Yk5kqjN3pCFURxP1NQ2W","name":"Haciendo Historia (Remasterizado)"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/05kjAktKUM6YDijNyHZMTa","name":"Después de un Beso - Remasterizado"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2G3l8Ca6mf4lVIJnX4QtDw","name":"Exceso de Equipaje (Remasterizado)"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/41MSad2qs3aL9C3PECzu3O","name":"Con un Canto en el Pecho - Remasterizado"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4HTwMqMGstCVL0YWEcIw3h","name":"Piano Y Ritmo"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5n8Zy0Jtsv2sXzpJoNQ0TT","name":"Aguardiente"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6rUbV5YhPvlqsYTXO3Mjig","name":"Qué Sorpresa"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0WEUAHwL8buyzLIM5NMgN5","name":"Qué Sorpresa"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3cN4DzawdHmneVAVQDtvjs","name":"20th Anniversary"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5bccusEjEtnC5cDfWXQ8rf","name":"Conciencia"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3dBUlScegJ59UI9M7QmsoU","name":"All That Vibe"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2udsBGAY4CA35nfUeS6GHL","name":"La Llave"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6885J4w1iaRdZbs8Ol4Zzs","name":"Mi Música"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/07TJxtp38iIauiPgh9pzIw","name":"Nena"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6fuOt44vgqDnAnZguOJecP","name":"Mis 30 Mejores Canciones"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4qsrxXxk4GCGih80VGmaAl","name":"Cara de Niño"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/33Ra3Yo9QmLr59J94djXl0","name":"La Palomilla - Single"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6Hqyh0Gqnri1DhkBAiceor","name":"La Palomilla"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1atq4NCh5u5kzxbRVN5Uyo","name":"Marcando la Distancia (La Nueva Generación de la musica Cubana)"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/70BDblSjPfj6Pe24avWzK2","name":"Marcando la Distancia"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2bbA92QOyasbJRtchOndvP","name":"Salsa Hits, Vol.1"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5f18XsUS3ZsuiilRWzkPla","name":"Devorame Otra Vez"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/39ZAmZKAsBo1v7cO9SqQWK","name":"Leche Condensada Feat. Milagros Piñera"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2Hg1XgItDFffo43HJdXg9H","name":"Fragilidad"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/25Y3ETSNfyM69wkkfDNWI1","name":"Entre Lo Bueno y Lo Malo"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0BAyGl0cUjS82JHb7DTCRk","name":"Entre Lo Bueno y Lo Malo"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6PWySeDAcKZihnTJBlf8hX","name":"Viceversa"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2Xg030uYjEA9FNiSKbD3R8","name":"Un Montón de Estrellas"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/034I6vHdPhI2GBviUn8SzN","name":"Spanish Guitar 4 (Backing Tracks)"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7D9BFAoAh8PDYVwOzeKG0l","name":"Stair Way to Heaven"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0OBXMlPSCxqZr4fQTcI5aN","name":"Me Dicen Cuba / Rosa la Peligrosa"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2AMQZ5IupHljTDOH44Nx2s","name":"Me Dicen Cuba"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/240xUkdH1C8OJhW6FZ1QXK","name":"Salsa Classic Hits, Vol. 1"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2f4WkmyUwwe37trgQ1RcMD","name":"La Cita"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3qIc0PZPMKTUEctOpZvB8r","name":"Salsa Pa' todo El Mundo"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4Yvm4q8WlxTgTR4kZwo6th","name":"Ain't No Sunshine"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0OBXMlPSCxqZr4fQTcI5aN","name":"Me Dicen Cuba / Rosa la Peligrosa"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0hpDDynkRmnH6BeW2IuLCE","name":"Rosa la Peligrosa"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6fuOt44vgqDnAnZguOJecP","name":"Mis 30 Mejores Canciones"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2VyxUBO64ggj5uFJJN5KyF","name":"Casi un Hechizo"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1HWR6jhbaQbAfVZlAzjZCW","name":"Mambo & Love"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/50UuxoLjhA43jsC8i2Tsp6","name":"Mambo & Love"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/38iX3I9Fltkp1vk2YVVMW4","name":"Mayimbe Full"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3JLnxur4bYdSiBO2Jxni43","name":"El Animal"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3WtBQZ96bgpLryiWNQ3t0D","name":"El Salsero De Ahora"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6paVGVOG0TCsLoJg56mw3S","name":"Amor Perfecto"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2T2Qxg14J0PUfXULOMaVC6","name":"A Lo Perucho"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7qLzN8cc7fWPgmaEzxySX9","name":"Amar y Querer"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7Mm5uiyXOjCbPruRVrS1xa","name":"La Terrorista"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7r37O0wFeeREBY74iYvTQx","name":"La Terrorista"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5FETAGgR5xYazWAtHFHqpL","name":"Guajiro Natural"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2o2HimAcKI66LRH8GUv5Wn","name":"Un Monton de Estrellas"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5X1QYXR9eQO3cYZrqeoIYE","name":"Oro Salsero"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/09Prj3ivNAC9Y80cP4eKnm","name":"Luna Negra"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1zkrBmI2CMM3z3fGoZVReP","name":"Legado"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3bpJ7IwjJtyTIf6clZ9GUl","name":"Amiga Mia"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0xgbPkhH5Hvuqa0hBGjpj3","name":"Lo Esencial"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4kWiuee1G91YS3QZJPTq4A","name":"No Morirá - No Matter What"}},{"track":{"album":{"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0upFuZDpxCxxFEMzorLsNc","name":"Soul of A Dancer"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4TqaLHhg8gbDQdQ9cGiHvt","name":"Beautiful"}}]}
```

My Model

```
export class Track {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public href: string,
        public album: {name: string, href: string}
    ) {}
}
```

Please can some one can help me ?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Run `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` at the top of your `map` and make sure it's what you think it is. Also, why not use the generic type, as in `this._http.get<Track[]>(...)` instead of the loop?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply,
The first time I used somthing like 
```
map((data) =>{return data.items as Track[]})
```
But I was unable to understand why my MatTable was initialized with empy values

By doing the loop I can clearly see that I can't read the attribut from occurences of my Track array